# BLE device no longer connectable in windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have been working on a BLE device using an arduino nano 33 BLE since this past May. During the summer and into the fall the device worked fine and I continued to develop my software. I took a break for a few months because I have been very busy in school.

I just recently came back to the device, however, my client software no longer works. The device is still able to connect to Windows, however, once I try to use the code `GattDeviceServicesResult result = await bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached).AsTask();` to connect to the device, it appears to connect (as indicated by an led on the Arduino) but then the GATT communication status becomes false, however, the device remains connected.

I fired up the universal Windows sample for Bluetooth LE to see if it could give me some insight as to what is happening, and it appears that the device is rapidly transitioning between being connectable and unconnectable.

This does not appear to be unique to the device as I have a BT speaker in my room that uses Bluetooth LE and it appears to be doing the same thing now as well. It also appears as though the event handlers for updating the device are being fired continuously.

This is a strange issue to suddenly occur so my only thought is that a Windows update between October and now broke the BLE functionality in Windows 10.

Any information on the issue is greatly appreciated. I am planning on possibly marketing this device and this would be a serious set back if BLE was now broken again in Windows 10. The device transmits a simple integer value, so nothing big.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Problem description:  https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/issues/114
  and solution: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/pull/95

Comment: Thank you, works great!